# access Request object in route group - Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim-3

I´m using Slim Framework and I need to access the Request object in a group so I can create objects and use them in the routes

```
$app->group('/my-group', function (App $app) {
    $id = $app->request->getAttribute('id')); // this doesn´t work
    $user = some_method_to_find_user($id)

    $app->get('/route-1', function () use ($user) {
        var_dump($user);
    }
}
```

how to access the Request object?

I also tried with

```
$app->group('/api', function (App $app, Request $request) {
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id')); // this doesn´t work
```

but is giving me this error:

```
 Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Closure::{closure}(),
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @DonHatch looks like I hit enter too fast. question updated

Answer (score 0):

groups are designed only to create Router (and by name - route groups)

you should use and access request only in Middlewares and Controllers (ie. clousures used as route)

during Group call the request might not be determined yet

application is building entire router (groups, each route,..)
and then by requested URI router will fill and pass Request to your middlewares and to route stack

use Slim Documentation, it is full of valid examples:

http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html#how-to-create-routes

```
$app->get('/books/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // Show book identified by $args['id']
});
```